# Login con Twitter en Laravel con artdarek/oauth-4-laravel

Tags: php, twitter-api, oauth, laravel-4

No entiendo cómo se usa este proveedor de servicio OAth:

Tengo un login creado, en donde, al ser un login, espero introducir ahí un correo y contraseña y un botón para hacer la petición.

Mi código, es este:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="account-box">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="/tweety.png" width="80px" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <h3 align="center">Twitvel</h3>
                <form class="form-signin" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                </div>
                <div class="btn btn-lg btn-block">
                  <a href="{{ url('auth/twitter') }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">
                    <strong>Autentificar con Twitter</strong>
                  </a>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y la ruta a la que hago la petición tiene este código:

```
Route::get('/auth/twitter', function(){
$token = Input::get( 'oauth_token' );
$verify = Input::get( 'oauth_verifier' );

// get twitter service
$tw = OAuth::consumer( 'Twitter' );

// check if code is valid

// if code is provided get user data and sign in
if ( !empty( $token ) && !empty( $verify ) ) {



// This was a callback request from twitter, get the token
    $token = $tw->requestAccessToken( $token, $verify );

    // Send a request with it
    $result = json_decode( $tw->request( 'account/verify_credentials.json' ), true );

    $message = 'Your unique Twitter user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
    echo $message. "<br/>";

    //Var_dump
    //display whole array().
    dd($result);

}
```

Y no entiendo si es correcto que en mis input ponga correo y contraseña, simplemente NO entiendo cómo hacer el login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, no se necesita un usuario ni una contraseña por ser un proveedor OAuth.**

Según [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth):

> OAuth permite a un usuario del sitio A compartir su información en el sitio A (proveedor de servicio) con el sitio B (llamado consumidor) sin compartir toda su identidad. Para desarrolladores de consumidores, OAuth es un método de interactuar con datos protegidos y publicarlos. Para desarrolladores de proveedores de servicio, OAuth proporciona a los usuarios un acceso a sus datos al mismo tiempo que protege las credenciales de su cuenta.

En otras palabras no necesitas un usuario ni una contraseña porque el usuario está utilizando su "usuario" de Twitter (en este caso) para autenticarse en tu sitio web. Es responsabilidad de tu sitio guardar la información proporcionada (como el token) por el servicio para que el usuario pueda seguir iniciando sesión en tu sitio sin tener que pedir permisos o algún otro tipo de información cada vez que se conecta el usuario (salvo comparar que sea el usuario correcto y que la aplicación tenga los permisos acordados).

---

Pasando a la programación como tal, solo necesitas (aparte de configurar el paquete):

Una vista con un botón de "Ingresar", algo similar a lo que tienes pero sin el usuario y la contraseña:

```
<a href="{{ url('auth/twitter') }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">
  <strong>Autentificar con Twitter</strong>
</a>
```

Una ruta (y un método en un controlador, preferiblemente), la cual se comunica con Twitter para pedir/verificar permisos.

```
Route::get('/auth/twitter', ......); // agrega controlador y método
```

En el controlador (agrega las dependencias respectivas):

```
public function logInTwitter() {

    $reqToken = $tw->requestRequestToken();

    // get Authorization Uri sending the request token
    $url = $tw->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()));

    // return to twitter login url
    return Redirect::to( (string)$url );

}
```

Por último, necesitarías otra ruta y otro método en el controlador para recibir la respuesta de Twitter, aunque en el ejemplo rápido de la documentación lo hacen todo en un solo método:

```
Route::get('/auth/response/twitter', ......); // agrega controlador y método
```

y en el controlador

```
public function processResponseTwitter()
    // get data from input
    $token = Input::get( 'oauth_token' );
    $verify = Input::get( 'oauth_verifier' );

    // get twitter service
    $tw = OAuth::consumer( 'Twitter' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $token ) && !empty( $verify ) ) {

        // This was a callback request from twitter, get the token
        $token = $tw->requestAccessToken( $token, $verify );

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode( $tw->request( 'account/verify_credentials.json' ), true );

        $message = 'Your unique Twitter user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
        echo $message. "<br/>";

        // Login ?
    } else {
       // Problems....
    }
```